# How does tf.gradients behave when passed a list of `ys` tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

How exactly does `tf.gradients` behave when passed a list of tensors as its first argument? Take this very small example:

```
a = tf.constant(5)
b = tf.constant(7)
c = a + 2 * b
```

If I compute the gradients of a single tensor, `c`, with respect to `[a,b]`, I get the expected answer:

```
grads = tf.gradients(c, [a, b])
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(grads) # returns (1, 2)
```

According to the Tensorflow documentation, if you pass in a *list* of tensors as your first argument `ys`, `tf.gradients` will sum the gradients over that list, returning `sum_over_ys(dy/dx)` for each `x` in your second argument. So I would expect:

```
tf.gradients([a, b, c], [a, b])
```

to behave the same way as:

```
tf.gradients(a + b + c, [a, b])
```

Am I reading the docs wrong? When I test this code, I get the expected result `[2, 3]` for the second expression (explicitly summing `a + b + c`), but `[2, 1]` for the first. Where is this `[2, 1]` coming from?

Comment: Weirdly, it works fine (as expected) if I take the derivative with respect to `[tf.identity(a), tf.identity(b), c]`. Is this a bug in TF, or are you just not supposed to include some of the `xs` in your list of `ys` for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that you are using `tf.constant`, which in theory shouldn't be affected by inputs.

If you replace your experiments with anything else (e.g. `Variables`) it works as expected.

When you apply an operator to the constant (be it addition, or even identity), you obtain a new tensor that is not `constant`, even though they depand on `constant`s only -- and therefore you obtain the expected behavior.